# How to get the information of encoded video from the Decoder TAppdecoderStatic HM model

Tags: encoder, decoder, hevc

I am trying to obtain the information (including Intra, motion vector, coeff) of compressed frames from the Decoder of HEVC Test Model. I used this command in Linux:

```
env PRINT_COEFF=1 PRINT_INTRA=1 PRINT_MV=1 SAVE_PREFILT=1 ./TAppDecoderAnalyserStaticd -b "BasketballDrive_1920x1080_50_50.bin"
-o "BasketballDrive_1920x1080_50_50.yuv"
```

But it only returns results like this

```
HM software: Decoder Version [11.0][Linux][GCC 7.5.0][64 bit] 

POC    0 TId: 0 ( I-SLICE, QP 27 ) [DT  0.049] [L0 ] [L1 ] [:,,,(unk)] 
POC    1 TId: 0 ( P-SLICE, QP 30 ) [DT  0.016] [L0 0 ] [L1 ] [:,,,(unk)]  
POC    2 TId: 0 ( P-SLICE, QP 29 ) [DT  0.019] [L0 1 0 ] [L1 ] [:,,,(unk)]  
POC    3 TId: 0 ( P-SLICE, QP 30 ) [DT  0.015] [L0 2 1 0 ] [L1 ] [:,,,(unk)]  
POC    4 TId: 0 ( P-SLICE, QP 28 ) [DT 0.017] [L0 3 2 1 0 ] [L1 ] [:,,,(unk)]  
POC    5 TId: 0 ( P-SLICE, QP 30 ) [DT  0.009] [L0 4 3 2 0 ] [L1 ] [:,,,(unk)]  
POC    6 TId: 0 ( P-SLICE, QP 29 ) [DT  0.011] [L0 5 4 3 0 ] [L1 ] [:,,,(unk)]  
POC    7 TId: 0 ( P-SLICE, QP 30 ) [DT  0.010] [L0 6 5 4 0 ] [L1 ] [:,,,(unk)]  
enter code hereTotal Time:        0.172 sec.
```

And the results I am expecting like this
[information from compressed video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzAk8.png)

Is there any solution to solve this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where those PRINT_X parameters are coming from. But according to the official HM code, they should do nothing.

Second, what do you mean intra mode or MV of a frame? The information you are asking are in the block level.

Block level information like these can be recorded during the parsing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Firstly, I am trying to run this code [link](http://www.mit.edu/~sze/fast.html). The goal is to use the information from the Decoder to accelerate the Super-Resolution algorithm applied to compressed video, rather than applying the SR algorithm on every frame. I also don't know how the author set PRINT_X parameters though I read documents
I am new to HEVC and I already misunderstand these are related to motion vector or residual matrix, your answer already helped me a lot.
How can I record the Block level information during the parsing? thanks

Comment: I took a look at the code provided in your link and I didn't find anything about HM or those PRINT_X arguments. Maybe you clear that up so I can help more precisely. (I explain how to extract block-level info in new comment)

Comment: Maybe those PRINT_X were modified in the code by the author. They just modified the code and set those arguments, The source code of this paper only contains the executable files without the source of the HM model so I do not know how to modify it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to log block-level information such as intra mode, MV, QP, partition size etc, you can do it simply during the parsing phase at the decoder side. In this phase, most syntax elements have dedicated functions to read their values from bitstream and copy them in the coding unit structure (all happens in `TDecSbac.cpp`)

For instance, you can go to `parseIntraDirLumaAng()` and take `intraPredMode` of the corresponding block. Or go to `parseCoeffNxN()` and take coefficient values stored in `pcCoef` array. Same about MV and other syntax elements.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I have tried to print some variables and make it again but this code is kind of confusing to me since I am new to HEVC code and not familiar with C++. I did not know how to modify it properly. I am gonna spend time to read this code. Your help and support are greatly appreciated!